# CSS ul li links issue

Tags: css, html-lists, hyperlink

I have this site here: http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/

At the bottom you will see social media icons and the issue I am having is when I put my mouse over them, they are not clickable, only when I move my mouse to the left a little bit and I do not understand what I did wrong:

HTML

```
<ul class="social-media">
<li class="twitter"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="instagram"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li class="facebook"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.social-media{
    padding-top:30px;
}

ul.social-media li{
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    list-style:none;
}

ul.social-media li.twitter{
    background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:0px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}

ul.social-media li.instagram{
    background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:-26px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}

ul.social-media li.facebook{
    background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:-52px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the clickable area depends on the content of the *a* tag. Your *a* tag does not have any content.
One solution is to apply your background image directly to the *a* tag and changing the *display* attribute to *block*.

```
ul.social-media li.twitter a {
  background-image:url(http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/images/social.png);
  background-position-x:0px;
  width:25px;
  height:26px;
  display: block;
}
```

Note that we also need to set *display* to *block* since the anchor tag is an inline element by default. The *width* and *height* attributes only have an effect on *block* elements.

Comment: Your answer is similar to mine and <a> still remains empty of relevant content, that unbreakable space he did set in it is not enough. But you are right too , the basic point is the display and size of <a> .

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the padding-left you have set on the li element

Answer (score 0):

it is probably because your links are so small.
try this :

```
 .social-media a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

So they fill entire `<li>` and stand over sprite.